# Class::Struct error: Can't locate object method

Tags: perl, struct

In order to simplify some existing tools, I wanted to replace several arrays with an array of structs.
So I made a simple example code to test the creation of the structs.  The code used is as follows:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#package Net_Node;
use Class::Struct Net_Node => [host => '$', access => '$', pass => '$'];
#struct( host => '$', access => '$', user => '$', pass => '$' );

my $example = new Net_Node;

$example->host('dir ip');
$example->access('TELNET');
$example->user('hjack');
$example->pass('buttstalion');

print "\n\n\n";
print "${example->host}\n";
print "${example->access}\n";
print "${example->pass}\n";
```

The issue is when I try to execute this script, I get this error:

```
Can't locate object method "host" via package "example" (perhaps you forgot to load "example"?) at test_2.pl line 15.
```

Can you please help me find out what do I need to correct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [Class::Struct EXAMPLES](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Struct#EXAMPLES), it looks like you need to call the `struct` function:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Class::Struct;

struct(Net_Node => [host => '$', access => '$', pass => '$']);

my $example = Net_Node->new();

$example->host('dir ip');
$example->access('TELNET');
$example->pass('buttstalion');

print $example->host, "\n";
print $example->access, "\n";
print $example->pass, "\n";
```

This prints:

```
dir ip
TELNET
buttstalion
```

Also, it seems `$example->host` won't interpolate inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has an error in structure accessor and you missed 'user' in `Class::Struct` definition

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

#package Net_Node;
use Class::Struct Net_Node => [host => '$', access => '$', user => '$', pass => '$'];
#struct( host => '$', access => '$', user => '$', pass => '$' );

my $example = new Net_Node;

$example->host('dir ip');
$example->access('TELNET');
$example->user('hjack');
$example->pass('buttstalion');

say "\n\n";
say $example->host;
say $example->access;
say $example->pass;
```

Output

```
dir ip
TELNET
buttstalion
```